# 9 Different Scenarios Requiring 9 Different AlertDialogs Anyway to Simplify Nested Dialogs?

Tags: android, dialog, nested, android-alertdialog

I have a scenario in my app where there are 9 potential dialogs a user should be shown depending on the conditions they've created in the app. While creating a single dialog is very simple using say the AlertDialog functionality, this becomes quite messy when you have multiple levels of nested dialogs.

Some of my scenarios require up to 3 nested dialogs to accomplish the control I need. You can imagine "dumb" nesting AlertDialogs takes up like 300 or so lines of code, is there any way to simplify this? Each dialog I am showing the user is different in some way, the buttons are almost always different as is the text displayed to the user in the title and message.

I thought of making a helper method to feed in the different buttons, their onClick code, the text for the title and message, etc. however, it was almost messier and more confusing than it was worth. I reverted back to simply dumb nested dialogs as it was just as clean in my opinion.

So, is it just par for the course to have hundreds and hundreds of lines of dialog code, or is there a smarter way to tackle my dumb nesting approach.

I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Implement AlertDialog, add the unimplemented methods and then set up a switch and case inside.
(DialogInterface.OnClickListener). I can help you more if you can elaborate more on what maybe the conditions are/combination of conditions.  You may even be able to store the conditions and results in two arrays which you can run subsequently.